# how to add straighten(gyro) function in side camera?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

How to get Straighten (gyroScope) in side camera?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIV5W.jpg)

i am using camera: ^0.10.4 this packege in side.

180 degree than center icon is green and other degree than center icon is red.
maintain gyro in camera.

Answer (score 0):

one of the easiest solutions is to have a Stack widget [Camera Stream Widget, Gyro Scope Widget], thus when you open this screen you will get the Gyro Scope on top of the camera.

Comment: can you give me the proper method?  code